# Mapping Document Reference Field from Firestore in Angular Service

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angular7, angularfire2

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I have a Firestore collection with some documents that have a document reference field.  I would like to map that field in the service and return a string from the linked document.  I can get the desired string from the database and print it to the console, but I can't get it to display in the application.

I've been fighting with this all morning.  I've tried a lot of ridiculous things, but the code I have should work.  I just feel like I'm missing something simple.  It appears from the console output that the code after the if statement is executing first.  I'm not sure why.

```
After if statement:
courses.service.ts:38 {active: true, name: "Honors 10", section: "1st", standardsRef: DocumentReference}
courses.service.ts:37 After if statement:
courses.service.ts:38 {active: true, name: "Honors 10", section: "2nd", standards: "Add Standards"}
courses.service.ts:37 After if statement:
courses.service.ts:38 {active: true, name: "English 10", section: "4th", standardsRef: DocumentReference}
courses.service.ts:37 After if statement:
courses.service.ts:38 {active: true, name: "Honors 10", section: "5th", standards: "Add Standards"}
courses.service.ts:31 From if statement:
courses.service.ts:32 {active: true, name: "Honors 10", section: "1st", standardsRef: DocumentReference, standards: "Honors 10"}
courses.service.ts:31 From if statement:
courses.service.ts:32 {active: true, name: "English 10", section: "4th", standardsRef: DocumentReference, standards: "English 10"}
```

courses.service.ts

```
getCourses() : Observable<Course[]> {
    return this.db.collection(`teachers/${this.userId}/courses`,
      ref => ref.orderBy('section')).snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(snaps => {
        return snaps.map(snap => {
          let course : Partial<Course> = snap.payload.doc.data();
          if (course.standardsRef) {
            this.db.doc(course.standardsRef).get()
              .subscribe(snap => {
                let standards = snap.data();
                course.standards = standards.name;
                console.log("From if statement:")
                console.log(course);
              });
          } else {
            course.standards = 'Add Standards';
          };
          console.log("After if statement:")
          console.log(course);
          return <Course> {
            id : snap.payload.doc.id,
            ...course
          };
        });
      }));
  }
```

I would expect my application to show the standards name from the database if there is a reference on the database and show "Add Standards" if there isn't.  The "Add Standards" is showing.  Where the name should be, it is blank.  I'm not getting any errors in the console.

I have no idea what I'm missing.  Thanks in advance.

## Edit

After messing around a bit, I extracted the nested observable and wrote two methods instead of one, and it seems to be working.  I will update if there are issues:

```
getCoursesDB() : Observable<Course[]> {
    return this.db.collection(`teachers/${this.userId}/courses`,
              ref => ref.orderBy('section'))
              .snapshotChanges()
              .pipe(map(snaps =>
              convertSnaps<Course>(snaps))
            );
  }

  getCourses() : Observable<Course[]> {
    let coursesDB = this.getCoursesDB();
    return coursesDB.pipe(map(courses => {
      return courses.map(course => {
        if (course.standardsRef) {
          this.db.doc(course.standardsRef).get()
            .subscribe(snap => {
              let standards = snap.data();  
              course.standards = standards.name;
            });
        } else {
          course.standards = "Add Standards";
        }
        return course;
      });
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Let's try to use `this.db.doc(course.standardsRef).snapshotChanges()` or `this.db.doc(course.standardsRef).valueChanges()` instead of `this.db.doc(course.standardsRef).get()`

Comment: I have the same problem with those.  Output is exactly the same.

Comment: I think I fixed it.  I have edited the OP with my solution.